# Warnings on arm64 when using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() with color_mode="rgb" on grayscale images for transfer learning

Tags: png, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I want to perform transfer learning with a pre-trained model that expects 3-channel input images such as VGG-16, but my images are grayscale. I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` with the `color_mode="rgb"` argument.

- On Google Colaboratory, with tensorflow==2.12.0, this works fine.
- On my MacBook Pro M1, with tensorflow-macos==2.12.0, I get countless warnings like the following:

```
: W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:88] PNG warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
```

and occasionally:

```
: W tensorflow/core/lib/png/png_io.cc:88] PNG warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50
```

How come I do not get these on Colab? And what is the correct way of achieving what I'm trying to do on Apple silicon, barring manually converting all files (e.g. using `PIL`'s `convert()` function)?

I'm aware that I can pre-process the images manually to have 3 identical channels, but I just want to know whether that is the only/best way to go about it or if I'm simply using the utility function `image_dataset_from_directory` incorrectly and there is a simpler way.

Thanks in advance.